# Авторизация через @react-oauth/google

Tags: reactjs, авторизация

Делаю авторизацию через @react-oauth/google, при клике на кнопку выходит окно с google с аккаунтом,
но в консоли выходит ошибка
client:273 Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy policy would block the window.closed call.
bq.A @ client:273
lc @ client:56
_.l.dispatchEvent @ client:55
_.Me.G @ client:125

дальнейшая авторизация не получается